# Geary set up "other" provider on Asus 1000he doesnt work

Tags: settings, pantheon-mail

The set up window expands on the bottom larger then screen size, so I can't finish the set up process? Possibly I just need to press some yes button. tried with pressing enter, but this just changes my settings in the Geary set up window.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A workaround to reach the hidden buttons:
Press and hold <kbd>Super</kbd> and drag the window at any position to move it up and reveal the hidden buttons.

You should [report this bug to Yorba](http://yorba.org/geary/help/bugs.html), the creators of Geary.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same Problem on the same machine (1000he).
I went to -> system settings -> Displays -> the little gear top right in the symbolised display -> rotation -> clockwise....
Then you can press the "yes button".
Then I rotated back again.
Did you find a better solution?
Otherwise elementary should work great on this machine.
Best operating system I ever installed on it.